# Codeigniter insert query for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, codeigniter

Code igniter insert statement automatically includes auto increment id in insert query. I am using the same query for inserting into SQL Server table, which causes issues with identity column as we all know. How can I modify the query to remove auto increment id from query? Or use the same query for inserting to SQL Server tables?

Comment: Kindly post your code please. Without that, we can't tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Actually insert query is working if i remove the auto-increment id from the query and manually insert each row in SQl server.But when i use $this->db->insert($data); this statement codeigniter automatically adding the auto increment id to the query which causes issues in sql server.

Comment: may be your column is auto increment in sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit query as you want manually.

Like as following

```
$sql= "INSERT INTO <tbl>(`ColumnName`) VALUES('value1')";
```

create function in your model which insert your query something like this...

Model File

```
<?php
 Model{
  function insertQuery($sql)
  {
    //database object make sure you load database in your model

    $this->db->query($sql);  

    // will insert your query as per you write and pass as argument

  }
 }
?>
```